# How do I change where Visual Studio looks for applicationhost.config?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I've looked all over this site and I cannot find the answer to this question.

Basically I'm trying to set up a new site for use with another project I'm working on. This site will run locally on my personal computer and will also be accessible via internet. So I installed IIS 7.5 Express and IIS Manager 7 to host this site. When I went into VS 2012 elevated to create a new site and map it to 'localhost', it pulled up the following error:

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

2nd attempt was by creating the site in a new directory by itself inside inetpub, just for the project itself and leaving wwwroot alone. When I do this, I get the following errors:

> Filename:
>
> \?\C:\Users\Joel\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
>
> Error: Cannot read configuration file
>
> File system Web sties are currently configured to use IIS Express. To switch back to using the Visual Studio Development server, change the development server option under the Projects and Solutions\Web Projects category of the Tools\Options menu.

When I browse the above location, applicationHost.config does not exist, but when I go to

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

I find it just fine. IIS Express 7.5 works fine and IIS Manager can find the default site just fine and will even let me browse it using my web browser. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this so that VS 2012 can create web sites and access the necessary files.

I run Windows 7 Professional x64 and I just finished installing IIS Express and IIS manager. I configured VS 2012 for Web Development. I ran VS as Administrator (elevated) for all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. I needed to manually set Visual Studio NOT to use IIS. Not sure what the issue is there.

But the solution is here for everyone else having this issue.

It was right there, I'm sure, when I was setting it up initially and I just missed it. After doing that, I could set up the new website to use the file system, which would bypass IIS anyway, but the setting to use IIS was conflicting with the bypass, which caused the error.

Hope this is superhelpful!